# Cast companion library android - addmediarouterbutton(View v)

Tags: android, google-cast

I am trying to integrate the cast sdk. I have read that this would be the easiest to achieve by using the CastCompanionLibrary-Android. So i have included it into my project. The only thing that i notice is that you can only add a MediaRouterButton via the ActionBar. In my particular usecase i am not using an ActionBar. But a custom view that contains ImageButtons.
Is it possible for me to easily integrate the cast companion library for Views instead of MenuItems?

Comment: I have the same question :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351364/castcompanionlibrary-and-not-extending-actionbaractivity

the short answer is no :(

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a `android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton` to your layout file

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of Activity that you are using. Are you inheriting from ActionBarActivity, FragmentActivity or AppCompatActivity? If yes, you can do that. You might want to read the documentation on CCL, section "Adding MediaRouteButton" to see how you can add a MediaRouteButton to your layout using CCL.